# What's the percentage of having two files with the same byte size length giving the same md5 hash?

Tags: md5

I'm developing an app that will store a lot of files, and in case of images, it will resize them and save the different thumbnails we need, so when a user uploads an image, it will save more 8 files (this is needed).

To avoid duplicated files and to save space on my static hosting server, my app is saving the file name as "MD5.BYTE_SIZE" (ex: 054d995efa7e9c91569d205d24a2b486.188154)

I've used this file scheme already on another clients without any problems, but I need to know, specifically to this project, if there exists the possibility of the user sending a file with the same MD5, and same size length.

If so, what's the best way to save my file names? With two different hashes (like MD5.SHA-256.BYTE_SIZE)?

Comment: This has already been covered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032209/is-md5-still-good-enough-to-uniquely-identify-files

They describe the probability as "vanishingly small".

Comment: Google "cryptographic hash".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For practical purposes, zero, unless the user actively tries to create two files that have the same hash, which is possible with MD5.

If you use SHA-256 instead, "zero" (for practical purposes) even if the user actively tries to create two files with the same size.

The exact probability is somewhere around 1/2^128 for two different files to generate the same hash. Due to the birthday paradoxon, you would need around 2^64 files until there is a 50% chance that two will have the same hash. Do not worry about it in practice. For SHA256, the numbers are 1/2^256 and 2^128, respectively. These numbers are also known as "not going to happen".

Comment: So, if my file name for each file were (MD5.SHA-256.BYTE_SIZE) the probability would be arround 1/2^128 * 1/2^256 ?

Comment: It would still be "zero for all practical purposes". Your calculation is correct, but the birthday paradox numbers may be more relevant to your application. The main advantage of using different hash functions is that attacks against a single function will not work. If someone manages to create two files that have the same SHA256 hash, he is famous and a lot of security stuff is broken. If someone manages to find two files that have the same MD5 *and* SHA256, the NSA will take care of him for you ;-) And we are talking about an attacker who can decide the content of both files, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible, but in reality the chance of two different files having the same MD5 checksum is vanishingly small.

So small, in other words, that you can essentially treat this event as impossible as far as your program is concerned.

Comment: My concern about this is if an malign user tries to upload an image with modified bytes, from the original, could replace my real data.

Comment: @CuSS, add a little logic to your upload code that prevents overwriting, perhaps by date or by username. one three-column data table would do ya.

Comment: @CuSS - Just don't allow an image to be replaced if it already exists.